# Move FontAwesome Icons OUTSIDE of li

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, css-position

I have what I feel should be a simple one, but its proving to be a tricky issue.

I simply have a `<ul>` with various `<li>` elements. 
Assigned to each LI is a font awesome icon.

My issue is that I want the icon to be OUTSIDE of the list item, at the moment it is inside and pushing the first line of text along, I want both lines of text to be inline next to the icon.

I have tried using the following:-

```
#skills-list li{
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

It seems that this only works on standard markers such as bullets etc. I have also tried targeting other classes such as:-

```
#skills-list li.i{...}

#skills-list li.a{...}
```

Is anyone able to assist, below is my code:-

```
<ul id="skills-list">
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> I aim to implement modern technologies into my projects using a movile first approach.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Exposing myself to GIT allows me to track, comment and update my project in a team repository.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Working with BOOTSTRAP frameworks allows implementation of elegant and modern design.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Learning SASS allowed me to speed up my web design process, creating fast and efficient CSS3.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Basic Understanding of JavaScript and JQuery means that I understand the process of DOM Manipulation.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> My previous background is in Animation, providing me with a good eye for detail and creativity.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi there. Is that to change the default dot of `ul li` to after selected use a check or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute positioning.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#skills-list li {
  position: relative;
}

#skills-list li i {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2em
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="skills-list">
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> I aim to implement modern technologies into my projects using a movile first approach.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Exposing myself to GIT allows me to track, comment and update my project in a team repository.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Working with BOOTSTRAP frameworks allows implementation of elegant and modern design.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Learning SASS allowed me to speed up my web design process, creating fast and efficient CSS3.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Basic Understanding of JavaScript and JQuery means that I understand the process of DOM Manipulation.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> My previous background is in Animation, providing me with a good eye for detail and creativity.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you have been a bit help, its amusing how much hair you can pull out over something so simple...

Answer (score 0):

You can try positioning the icons () outside the corresponding list item using position: absolute;

I don't know the actual visual result you're trying to achieve, but it should be something like:

```css
li {
  position: relative;
}

i {
  position absolute;
  left: -24px;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mark the list as unstyled using bootstraps typography classes

```
<ul id="skills-list" class="list-unstyled">
```

Run the snippet to see:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul id="skills-list" class="list-unstyled">
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> I aim to implement modern technologies into my projects using a movile first approach.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Exposing myself to GIT allows me to track, comment and update my project in a team repository.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Working with BOOTSTRAP frameworks allows implementation of elegant and modern design.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Learning SASS allowed me to speed up my web design process, creating fast and efficient CSS3.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> Basic Understanding of JavaScript and JQuery means that I understand the process of DOM Manipulation.</li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> My previous background is in Animation, providing me with a good eye for detail and creativity.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
      <ul id="skills-list">
        <i class="fas fa-check-square"></i><li> I aim to implement modern technologies into my projects using a movile first approach.</li>
      </ul>
```

Is that all you want?

Comment: are you serious ?

Comment: Am I serious? No I'd say I am quite a fun guy :)